# Wordpress Fancy box title not showing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, title

I am trying to build a website using wordpress, one of the plugins I have is to help create a hotspot on images (54.165.58.29/dahlia/ This is the page). I am unable to get the title to appear in the pop-up display for the images.

This is the code here.

```
$_ = jQuery.noConflict();
$_(document).ready(function() {   
        $_("a[rel=map_gallery]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
            'titleFormat' : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts)

{ return '<span id="fancybox-title-inside">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' +    currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
}
});                                       
});
```

I have exhausted to many hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the title attribute to each a tag in your code for fancy box to pick it up.

```
<a id="197_mark_image_1" href="http://54.165.58.29/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/MB2.jpg" class="btn" rel="map_gallery" style="  position: absolute; top:39px; left:152px; " title="My image title">
  <!--img src="http://54.165.58.29/wp-content/plugins/floorplan-generator/images/camera-button.png" /-->
  <div onclick="addToFancyboxWrap(this)" style=" width: 30px;height: 30px;-moz-border-radius: 50px;-webkit-border-radius: 50px;border-radius: 50px;color: #fff;"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/circle_pink_hotspot2.png"></div></a>
```